# Mybatis null value for resultype hashmap

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, mybatis, resulttype

```
<select id="getData" parameterType="Object" resultType="map"> 
    select query.* from (${query}) query 
</select>
```

So this is the query I want to execute. Although the query is correct and returning the desired data, but when the data is inserted in the resultType **map** as specified the null values present in some of the columns get omitted.

I have searched/googled for the same, but not got what I want. I also viewed [this link](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/hashmap-resultType-and-null-values-td3448220.html), but can't get my answer.

Is there any way to get those omitted/disappeared values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the setting `callSettersOnNulls`, see [here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html). The default is false, so no setter will be called on a `null` value, but you can set it to true.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this issue ?? 
<br>callSettersOnNulls is a good approach but version incompatibilty problem is there with my case.

Comment: Thanks Florian, but i am using Mybatis version 3.0.6, and this is for Version: 3.2 + version . Can i do anything else ?

Comment: Besides not using a map, but some custom class (which could be extending (Hash)Map, of course) that behaves correctly, for example be initializing all fields in the constructor, I haven't got an idea there, sorry.